# Como acessar uma variavel de ambiente com .(ponto) no nome

Tags: linux, variáveis

Olá, alguém sabe me dizer como acessar uma variável de ambiente com .(ponto) no nome usando terminal linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente isso não é possível (em BASH). Apenas caracteres alfanuméricos e underscores são permitidos.

```
export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...

name   A  word  consisting  only  of alphanumeric characters and under‐
      scores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an  under‐
      score.  Also referred to as an identifier.
```

Fonte em inglês: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93532/exporting-a-variable-with-dot-in-it